# Laravel forbid updating row if its referenced in another table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

say Table A and Table B (table B has a foreign key a_id)
I want to be able to update a row in A as long as it's not ref in B
I already did it but I'm looking for a better approach.

My approach

```
$referencesInB = TableB::where('a_id', $id)->exists();
if ($referencesInB) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Cannot update'], 403);
}
$rowA->update($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$referencesInB = TableB::where('a_id', $id)->exists();
```

You can avoid the extra query check above(saving us a few milliseconds or *more*) by eager loading the relation and checking if the relation actually loaded. So, it all happens with 1 query instead of 2 eliminating the `N + 1` query issue
[`docs`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

```
<?php

$rowA = TableA::with('table_b')->find($id);

if ($rowA->relationLoaded('table_b')) {
  return response()->json(['error' => 'Cannot update'], 403);
}

$rowA->update($request->all());
```

Comment: My question was if I could do it without this kind of approach
(searching for b in a) ?
like for example something in the migration of the table similar to onDelete etc..

Comment: @Zein Not sure if anything like that exists. Why would you not want to do this? onDelete, onUpdate cascade are a bit different from your use case.

Comment: yes I know that I just don't want this to be feasible since without the check you can update it 
I want it in a way that it will fail when trying to update 
thank you for your help I'll keep the if statement for now lol

Comment: @Zein A before update trigger was the closest to your use case but I am afraid, it won't stop the update query execution if some criteria is met in the before trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it upstream where you first get `$rowA`

```
$rowA = TableA::whereDoesntHave('B')->findOrFail($id);

//or

$rowA = AClass::whereDoesntHave('B')->find($id);
if (!$rowA) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Cannot update'], 403);
}
```

`'B'` is the name of the relation difined in TableA model class